# how to invoke viewpart by java code in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I invoke viewpart class on menu command event in eclipse plugin project. Basically I want to open an awt frame inside eclipse plugin so I am using viewpart class for that. Awt frame should open when user requests it.

I have created a menu option and I want to open that awt frame on that menu command. I have tried to make class of viewpart and then call it but it did not work. Below is my code of viewpart class

```
public class LabelView extends ViewPart {
    public static Composite _parent;
    private Label label;
    public LabelView() {
        super();
    }
    public void setFocus() {
        //label.setFocus();
    }
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        _parent=parent;

        // main composite
        Composite mainComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);

        Frame awtframe = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(mainComposite);
        java.awt.Panel  awtpanel   = new java.awt.Panel();
        awtpanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());
        awtframe.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());
        awtframe.add(awtpanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'invoke viewpart class'? Is this view already open and you want to do something in the view? Or do you want to open the view?

Comment: @greg-449 in both condition, when viewpart is open and i want to update something and also if viewpart is close then first i open it then change

Answer (score 0):

To find the view use:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart view = page.findView("view id");
```

where "view id" is the id of the view that you declared in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point.

If the view is not open `view` findView will return null, you can open the view using:

```
view = page.showView("view id");
```

In either case you can then cast the view to your view class and call a method to do what you want:

```
LabelView myView = (LabelView)view;

myView.someMethod();  // TODO you write this method
```

Comment: i am facing an issue that when the viewpart is open, it do not update/refresh view. When i manually close and open viewpart it work fine but by java code it do not refresh or update. What can i do for it?